# ImageMagick: Replace All Image Tiles with Single Tile

Tags: imagemagick, overlay, placeholder, tile, tiling

I'm assuming ImageMagick is the best option for this, but please let me know if you have other recommendations that can be scripted.

I am trying to replace all the 32x32 tiles of an image with a single tile. This is an example for the original image:

[image: Original]

This is the tile that I want to use to replace all tiles on the original image:

[image: Placeholder tile]

And this is what I want the output to be:

[image: Placeholder image]

I've figured out from other posts on Stack Overflow that I can use ImageMagick's *composite* option to overlay the tile onto the original image:

`$ convert original.png tile.png -composite overlay.png`

Resulting in the following:

[image: Overlay]

And I assume by knowing the original images dimensions I can overlay the tile manually multiple times. But is there a way to automate the process. In the example pictures I have given, I need to overlay the tile 8 times on the original 64x128 image.

How can I do this with ImageMagick or another software? And if ImageMagick, would the *montage* or *composite* command be a better option?

**Edit:** As an additional question, would it be possible to skip tiles that are completely transparent?

Input example:

[image: Original transparent]

Output example:

[image: Placeholder transparent]

It isn't really important to be able to do this part, but would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tile image fits evenly into the dimensions of the original, a command like this should do most of what you want...

```
convert original.png tile.png -background none -virtual-pixel tile \
   -set option:distort:viewport %[fx:u.w]x%[fx:u.h] -distort SRT 0 +swap \
   -compose copyopacity -composite overlay.png
```

That reads in both images. Then it creates another canvas the size of the original and filled with multiple copies of the tile image. Then it uses the original as a transparency mask to create a copy of the new tiled image with the same transparent cells as the original.

Comment: I may have done something wrong, but this command gave me two files: "overlay-0.png" & "overlay-1.png". "overlay-0.png appears to be a copy of "tile.png", & "overlay-1.png" is a copy of "original.png".

Comment: Okay, I must have done something wrong to begin with, because I copied & pasted your command which had a different output. It still gave me two files, "overlay-0.png" & "overlay-1.png". But this time, "overlay-0.png" had my desired output. Any way to suppress outputting the 2nd file & the addition of the "-0" suffix?

Comment: I'm sorry, it appears when I copy/pasted the command I left out a bit of it. I've edited the command now to add "-compose copyopacity -composite" right after the "+swap". Try that, and if it still doesn't do what you want we can try to fix it to to work.

Comment: Thank you very much GeeMack. At first I was a little skeptical that this method didn't completely block out each tile, but rather retained transparency & only covered opaque pixels. But actually, I have decided that this works perfectly for what I want to use it for.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you would need to overlay the 8 tiles on the original. Just create it from scratch and name the output the same as your original

You could use Imagemagick montage to do that (unix syntax):

```
nx=`convert original.png -format "%[fx:w/32]" info:`
ny=`convert original.png -format "%[fx:h/32]" info:`
num=$((nx*ny-1))
montage tile.png -duplicate $num -tile ${nx}x${ny} -geometry +0+0 result.png
```

[image]

Here I use convert to duplicated the tile, but it uses a relatively current -duplicate feature. If you do not have a current enough version of Imagemagick, then just repeat the tile in montage as follows:

```
montage Ro1Lp.png Ro1Lp.png Ro1Lp.png Ro1Lp.png Ro1Lp.png Ro1Lp.png Ro1Lp.png Ro1Lp.png -tile 2x8 -geometry +0+0 result.png
```

Comment: You are correct, I do not need to "overlay" the original image. But, I have many images of different sizes, all with dimensions that are multiples of 32. This answer does work for me. I just need to get the dimensions of the original image, which can be done with `identify original.png | cut -d " " -f 3`. Then I just need to divide the *x* & *y* values by 32.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the computations of the number of tiles.

Comment: I want to thank you very much for this answer. It was hard to decide between yours & GeeMack's, & I implemented both of them into a script. I wish I could choose multiple, because I think this one answers the question just as well.

Comment: Can you not up-vote both? I thought that was possible. But perhaps not for the person writing the question.

Comment: Yes, I up-voted both of them. But I can only choose one as *accepted answer*.

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Fred (fmw42) says, *"why don't you just create the whole image from scratch?"*.

Maybe your description isn't complete, so here are a couple more pieces that might help you work it out.

Given `bluetiles.png` and `singlered.png`:

[image] [image]

you can position red ones as you wish like this:

```
convert bluetiles.png \
   singlered.png -geometry +0+32  -composite \
   singlered.png -geometry +32+96 -composite result.png
```

[image]

---

Given `bluewithtransparent.png`:

[image]

you can copy its transparency to the newly-created image like this:

```
convert bluetiles.png \
   singlered.png -geometry +0+32  -composite \
   singlered.png -geometry +32+96 -composite \
\( bluewithtransparent.png -alpha extract \) -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

[image]